# Node: Setting the error message and sending it back to UI

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node server is posting to a third party website and getting the response back.
 If the response contains something like `Password didn't match.`, server will send error to UI something like `400: Bad password.`. Else sever will analyze the response and send part of data from it.
 I am not able to send `errorMessage` back to UI. How can I return an error object from anaylzeData method and send it back to client?
**Code:**

```
app.post('/login', [express.urlencoded(), express.json()], function(req, res) {
    request.post({
      url: 'http://teeSpring.com/login/submitLogin',
      form: {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error is: '+JSON.stringify(error));
        res.send(400, "There is some problem  here.");  
      } else if(body){
        console.log('Body is :')//+JSON.stringify(body));
        var serverResp = analyzeData(body);
        console.log('Server Response is :'+serverResp);
        res.send(serverResp);
      }
   });
});

analyzeData = function(responseData) {
  var respModel=[];
  var errorMessage;
  $ = cheerio.load(responseData);
  $(".errors > p").each(function(i, element) {
    console.log($(this).text().indexOf("The password you entered is incorrect"));
    if ($(this).text().indexOf("The password you entered is incorrect") >= 0) {
      console.log('finds the error')
      var error = new Error("Password did not match");
      error.code = 400;
      errorMessage = error;
      return false;
    }; 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything for success case on analyzeData()